# Adding Listener for TreeViewerColumn

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, viewer, treeviewer

I have a treeviewer with dynamic number of columns. I am using *ColumnLabelProvider*. Every column cell is populated with a image (not text) using *getImage()* method of labelProvider.

I need a listener that will be triggered when i double click on column cell and an editor should be opened upon double click. I tried using selection listener for tree column but that doesn't work.

My tree item already has a listener that performs another operation so this listener that i add for column should be independent of it. This is the reason
i didnt create my tree using `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` because if i use full selection the operation intended for my tree item is performed though i double click the column cell.

Comment: You use `EditingSupport` for this on tables and tree. See for example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#tutorial-editing-the-table-content)

Comment: Unable to select my TreeViewerColumn, unless i create the tree with swt.full_selection. But since i already have a seperate action for tree item double click, i dont want the same action to happen on column doubleclick also.

Comment: EditingSupport doesn't require SWT.FULL_SELECTION. It actually triggers on single click and you can choose which columns can be edited.